# How can I extract sequences from FASTA file using OTUs ID?

Tags: fasta

I have one FASTA file with sequences and headers, and one OTUs table.
What I want to do is replace the current headers in the FASTA file with just the OTU IDs from the .txt file. The files look like something like this:

FASTA file:

```
>9d4544fa-322a-4fac-bcf5-f8ca410c7e8a runid=b48dcb2029ef589b8cdb55fe529d93b3baadbc7c sampleid=28012021COVID3 read=57150 ch=310 start_time=2021-01-28T18:23:35Z
TCAGTTACGTATTGCTGGTGCTGAAGAAAGTTGTCGGTGTCTTTGTGTTAACCTTTCTGTTGGTGCTGATATTGCAGTCGCCCCCACCTCCTTGGATCCGCCAGGTTAAACACCCAAGCAGACGCCGAAGATAGAGCGACAGGCAAGTAGGTTAACACAAAGACACCGACAACTTTTCTTCCAGCACCAGCAGCCCGTAACT
>a8d321b9-97f1-42aa-a17a-fa1c4609e60e runid=b48dcb2029ef589b8cdb55fe529d93b3baadbc7c sampleid=28012021COVID3 read=46034 ch=83 start_time=2021-01-28T18:24:16Z
CGTTCGGTGCGTATTGCTGGTGCTGAAGAAAGTTGTCCGGTGTCTTTGTGTTAACCTTTCTGTTGGTGCTGATATTGCGGCGTCTGGCAGGTGTTAACCTGGCCTCGAGAGAGTTTGATCCTGGCTGGGATGAACGCTGACGTGCCTAATACATGCAAGTAG
>6d97cca8-6795-4c59-b4d1-05880735b957 runid=b48dcb2029ef589b8cdb55fe529d93b3baadbc7c sampleid=28012021COVID3 read=46363 ch=227 start_time=2021-01-28T18:24:08Z
GTTCAGTGCATATTGCTGTGGTGCTGCGAAAGTTTGTGGTGTCTTTGTGTTAACGCTTTCTGTTGGTGCTGATATTGCGGCGGCGTCTGCGCGGTGTTTAACCTGGCGGATCAAGGAGGTGTTCAGCCGCACCTTCCGTTTTGACTACGCCATTACGACTGCCCAATCTGTTTTACCCTAGGCCCGATCCTTGCGGTCACGGACTTCAGGCACCCCCGGCTTTCATGGCTTGACAGGCGGTGTGTACAAGGCCCGGGAACATTCACCCGCGCCATGGCTGATGCGCGATTACTAGCGAATCCCAGCTTCACGGGTCGGGTTGCA
>772e0bef-fad4-4767-b0e6-d88e6f16b2ed runid=b48dcb2029ef589b8cdb55fe529d93b3baadbc7c sampleid=28012021COVID3 read=49763 ch=349 start_time=2021-01-28T18:24:10Z
CGTTCAGTTACGTATTGCTGGTGCTGAAGAAAGTTGTCGGTGTCTTTAGGTTAACCTTTCTGTTGGTGCTGATATTGCGGCGTCTGCTTGGGTGTTTAACCTGGCCTCGAGAAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGGATGAACGCTAGCTTCTGAGCTTAACATGCAGAGTCCAGGGCAGCATGGAAGAAACTGCTTCTTCTGATGGCGACAACGCACGGGTGCATGCGCGTATCAAACCTGCCTCATA
>2b673c48-69c9-48a4-995b-4ad630e23502 runid=b48dcb2029ef589b8cdb55fe529d93b3baadbc7c sampleid=28012021COVID3 read=71966 ch=124 start_time=2021-01-28T18:24:11Z
TTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTGCTGGTGCTGAAAGTTGTCGGTGTCTTTGTGTTAACCTTTCTGTTGGTGCTGATATTGCGGCTCTGCTTGGGTGTTTAACCTGGCGGATCAAGGAGTGTTAGCCGCACCTTCCGGTACCAACTACCTTGTTACGACTTAGCCCC
```

OTUs table:

```
OTU ID  IA1 IA2 IA3 IA4 IA5 IS6
otu500  7   10  3   0   5   0
otu502  7   8   4   0   11  1
otu504  4   5   6   2   4   2
otu505  4   4   6   2   8   3
```

and my desired output is that the .fasta file would look like this:

```
>otu500
tggggaatcttagacaatgggcgcaagcctgatctagccatgccg
>otu502
tgaggaatattggtcaatggaggcaactctgaaccagccatgccttggtcaatggaggc
>otu504
gcgaacaggattagataccctggtagtccacgccgtaaacttggtcaatggaggc
>otu505
ttggtcaatggaggcttggtcaatggaggctaccctggttaccctggt
>otu506
```

Comment: There is not enough information here to label the fasta sequences with their OTU assignments. What program did you use to produce the OTU table? The program should have a way to list each sequence's OTU assignment. For example, in the mothur program, the [cluster command](https://mothur.org/wiki/cluster/) outputs a [list file](https://mothur.org/wiki/list_file/).

Comment: There seems to be some missing info - I can't see any logical mapping between reads and OTU table - do you have an OTU sequence file?